# Using pyMongo and APscheduler with Gunicorn --preload option

Tags: python, flask, pymongo, gunicorn, apscheduler

I start **gunicorn** with 3 workers (`--workers 3`) to launch a **flask** app and jobs configured with **APscheduler**. In order to launch my jobs just once (and not once per worker) I use the `--preload` option.

However, my issue is that I also use **pyMongo** which does not work safe with the **gunicorn** `--preload` option :

```
/Users/xxx/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py:149: UserWarning: MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient only after forking. See PyMongo's documentation for details: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#is-pymongo-fork-safe
  "MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient only "
```

How can I work with those three packages together with no issue?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am seeing this error as well, and don't really follow its meaning.

Comment: This seems relevant: http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#multiprocessing